# Load data from file in Play framework YAML

Tags: playframework, yaml, load-data-infile

I would like to load some data stored in a file into my mysql database when play is applying evolution to the database.

Basically when play is running the 1.sql to upgrade the database, I would like to run a "LOAD DATA INFILE" or equivalent.

Maybe there is an equivalent existing in yaml for LOAD DATA INFILE ?

If yes, how could I achieve something similar to
`LOAD DATA INFILE "/path/to/myfile" INTO TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

Thanks

Comment: What db server are you using ? MySQL, H2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative to this problem,

in the global.java, when the application is restarted I check if my table is empty with
`if(Ebean.find(MyClass.class).findRowCount() == 0)`
and then I read my file in a classic way with FileInputStream, split the line with the java string split() function and update mysql table with  the save() function of my model

Answer (score 0):

The `LOAD DATA INFILE` is [MySQL specific](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html). You have to use the syntax used by this MySQL command.

AFAIK, you can use this MySQL statement to load your data from your Evolution's SQL file. The tricky part is to properly locate your data file, because the evolution files are stored in your app jar (ie in your classpath) when you use the `play dist` command. so you have to be carefull when you want to deploy in production, and add the data files in the generated zip.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I ended up finding an alternative for this problem